# Cohomology in Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, homology-cohomology

Below is a communicative diagram:

$$\begin{array}[c]{ccc}
C^{\infty}(M)&\stackrel{\text{grad}}{\longrightarrow}&\Gamma(M)&\stackrel{\text{curl}}{\longrightarrow}&\Gamma(M)&\stackrel{\text{div}}{\longrightarrow}&C^{\infty}(M)\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow&&\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
\Omega^0(M)&\stackrel{\text{d}}{\longrightarrow}&\Omega^1(M)&\stackrel{\text{d}}{\longrightarrow}&\Omega^2(M)&\stackrel{\text{d}}{\longrightarrow}&\Omega^3(M)&
\end{array}$$

This diagram occurs in Lee's book *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* on page 372.

This shows that the first chain complex is isomorphic to the De Rham cohomology. I am curious about

> Is there any analogy of the first chain in higher dimensional Riemannian manifold?

Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. The second chain. (The thing you actually want to know about is called Hodge duality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual)

Comment: (I should clarify: the thing you actually want to know about is the isomorphism between the two complexes. The first complex itself is a bit unnatural since in higher dimensions it amounts to applying Hodge star to only half of the de Rham complex.)